# How do I Fix PowerShell Module Nesting Limit Error?

Tags: powershell

I get the following error message in the console before the first line of my script executes:

```
InvalidOperation: Cannot load the module 'C:\Users\Dave\Documents\WebPublisher\modules\WebPublisherUploader\WebPublisherUploader.psm1' because the module nesting limit has been exceeded. Modules can only be nested to 10 levels. Evaluate and change the order in which you are loading modules to prevent exceeding the nesting limit, and then try running your script again.
```

There’s no circular reference in the WebPublisherUploader that I can see, though if I trace the chain far enough down, another module imported in a module that it imports seems to point back to WebPublisherUploader. Would this be what causes the error?

And how does one “change the order in which you are loading modules”? Is there a way to control load order that I don’t know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, there were circular module imports going on, but the import chain was so long it was hard to see them.

It turned out the solution was simple once I identified the problem.  The problem module had a couple of enum definitions which were needed by many other modules. So I simply created a new module, called XxxTypes.psm1, **with no imports**, and moved the enum definitions there.

With no imports in XxxTypes.psm1, there’s no longer any danger of accidentally creating another circular import chain.

Problem solved. Whew!